# what are difference between launcher background and foreground in drawable?

Tags: android

1. I want to copy images import to project but it has 2 kinds in res-drawable that ic_launcher_background and ic_launcher_foreground(v24) so I don't know what are difference between of those.
2. One more thing, sometime, images exist in drawable but in code can't find out. I have to edit or change extention image file and import again and code recognize. How to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ic_launcher_background` and `ic_launcher_foreground` are used for creating [adaptive icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive) which create two layers for your launcher icon.

Comment: So if I want to make the listview like gallery, so those image where I will to import? foreground or background?

Comment: If you want to use launcher icons, then you need to keep them in your `mipmap` folder and for other icons use `drawable` folder

Comment: Thanks Saurabh, so image for icon will put in mipmap folder. And image for background or photo... use for drawable? is it?

Comment: App icon that is seen on your phone's launcher will go in `mipmap` and other image assets like close button icon or add button icon will go in `drawable`. Also, mark the answer as accepted if you got the answer for your question.

Comment: Thanks Saurabh, i got it. Also, why sometime in code not recognize image even it existed in drawable?
And How to mark the answer?

Comment: If you're writing it correctly and it's still not recognizing you can clean and rebuild your project, which might solve the issue. And to mark the answer, click on the tick mark next to that answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you drag your app on to the screen, the foreground will start moving with delay to emulate a "cool" effect, that's all its for.